# CRON @reboot vncserver?

Tags: linux, vnc, cron

Is there any reason per-user cronjobs running vncserver `@reboot` wouldn't run?

When I reboot the machine and look into `/var/log/syslog`, I see the jobs being run, then cron saying `(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`.

I'd rather not configure postfix just to figure out why these jobs aren't running, but I'm not sure I have another choice here. Unless the program mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82093/minimal-mta-that-delivers-mail-locally-for-cron) will yield me the email data.

EDIT:

Well, I installed femtomail per its readme, but got this from cron: `MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x0001, #012)`.

One byte? That hardly seems like it could be an error code.

Comment: It sounds like the cron jobs are being run. Your only problem is with mailing the output of the cron jobs to the users, which is a totally separate issue. I'm not sure why it doesn't do local mail delivery.

Comment: The issue is that the vncserver processes aren't running when I check after reboot. I figured that's why cron would be trying to mail me.